# In React-Admin, could I disable the mailto link created by EmailField?

Tags: react-admin

I'm setting an admin panel and listing the users that are registered in a platform.

In the listing page, when I click over the row I am linked to edit page. However, one of the fields is 'email' and I use EmailField to get advantage of validations, what it automatically creates an anchor tag with a mailto functionality.

For all the fields I am showing, 'email' is the unique field that has a link so, from the UX point of view, it invites to click it. And when I click over the link, the email client is opened. That is why I want to disable the link.

I could change to TextField, but I want to keep EmailField's validations. So, is there a way to avoid creating a mailto anchor over the email? I can't find it in the docs or in google.

```
export const UserList = props => (
        <List bulkActionButtons={false} {...props} filters= 
   {<UserFilter/>} perPage={10} sort={{ field: 'email', order: 'ASC' 
}} pagination={<UserPagination />} >
            <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
                <EmailField source="email" />
                <BooleanField source="isAdmin" />
                <EditButton />
                <DeleteButton />
            </Datagrid>
        </List>
);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand, in the list view, the `EmailField` doesn't make any validation. You can display the Email in the list view with a `TextField` and keep the `EmailInput` in the Create and Edit views. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right! It is solved thanks to your answer. I am newbie with React-Admin.... Thanks @Kmaschta.